# How to upgrade eclipse from juno to kepler

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno IDE for android development. I wanna upgrade my eclipse version to Kepler.

Comment: Which problem did you face in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally you won't be able to upgrade Eclipse or certain features due to incompatible changes in the update technology. Better way to upgrade from juno to kepler is download the new version and install.
Complete upgrade instructions are always included in the Eclipse ***readme_eclipse.html*** file included with every build in the ***readme*** directory.